# Docker buildx qemu: uncaught target signal 7 (Bus error) - core dumped

Tags: python, docker

I want to build a multi-platform image of a little python app on my Windows 11 PC. I am running Docker Desktop 4.10.1 (82475) and the commands in Windows PowerShell. I have no idea what this error means or why it is crashing or just not running there in an endless loop. I cannot find anything about target signal 7 on the internet which is weird.

Does anybody have an idea?

`docker buildx ls` shows me:

```
NAME/NODE       DRIVER/ENDPOINT                STATUS  PLATFORMS
build           docker-container
  build         npipe:////./pipe/docker_engine running linux/amd64, linux/amd64/v2, linux/amd64/v3, linux/arm64, linux/riscv64, linux/ppc64le, linux/s390x, linux/386, linux/mips64le, linux/mips64, linux/arm/v7, linux/arm/v6
mybuilder *     docker-container
  mybuilder0    npipe:////./pipe/docker_engine running linux/amd64, linux/amd64/v2, linux/amd64/v3, linux/arm64, linux/riscv64, linux/ppc64le, linux/s390x, linux/386, linux/mips64le, linux/mips64, linux/arm/v7, linux/arm/v6
desktop-linux   docker
  desktop-linux desktop-linux                  running linux/amd64, linux/arm64, linux/riscv64, linux/ppc64le, linux/s390x, linux/386, linux/arm/v7, linux/arm/v6
default         docker
  default       default                        running linux/amd64, linux/arm64, linux/riscv64, linux/ppc64le, linux/s390x, linux/386, linux/arm/v7, linux/arm/v6
```

I created build and mybuilder.

The command I'm trying to run is:

```
docker buildx build --platform linux/arm/v7,linux/arm64/v8,linux/amd64 --tag username/imagename:latest .
```

The building logs:

```
[+] Building 67.2s (16/18)
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.22kB                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => [linux/arm/v7 internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:alpine                                                                                                                               0.9s
 => [linux/arm64 internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:alpine                                                                                                                                0.9s
 => [linux/amd64 internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:alpine                                                                                                                                0.9s
 => [linux/arm/v7 1/4] FROM docker.io/library/python:alpine@sha256:4543fd9295d8d4f7a61c80d8e490de0f1cb0b37b022dbc1dd92537101a81d149                                                                         0.0s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/python:alpine@sha256:4543fd9295d8d4f7a61c80d8e490de0f1cb0b37b022dbc1dd92537101a81d149                                                                                      0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring context: 94B                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => [linux/arm64 1/4] FROM docker.io/library/python:alpine@sha256:4543fd9295d8d4f7a61c80d8e490de0f1cb0b37b022dbc1dd92537101a81d149                                                                          0.0s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/python:alpine@sha256:4543fd9295d8d4f7a61c80d8e490de0f1cb0b37b022dbc1dd92537101a81d149                                                                                      0.0s
 => [linux/amd64 1/4] FROM docker.io/library/python:alpine@sha256:4543fd9295d8d4f7a61c80d8e490de0f1cb0b37b022dbc1dd92537101a81d149                                                                          0.0s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/python:alpine@sha256:4543fd9295d8d4f7a61c80d8e490de0f1cb0b37b022dbc1dd92537101a81d149                                                                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [linux/arm64 2/4] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => CACHED [linux/arm64 3/4] COPY . .                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => CACHED [linux/amd64 2/4] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => CACHED [linux/amd64 3/4] COPY . .                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => CACHED [linux/amd64 4/4] RUN pip3 install python-tado                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => CACHED [linux/arm/v7 2/4] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => CACHED [linux/arm/v7 3/4] COPY . .                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => [linux/arm64 4/4] RUN pip3 install python-tado                                                                                                                                                         66.3s
 => => # qemu: uncaught target signal 7 (Bus error) - core dumped
 => [linux/arm/v7 4/4] RUN pip3 install python-tado                                                                                                                                                        66.3s
 => => # qemu: uncaught target signal 7 (Bus error) - core dumped
```

And last but not least my Dockerfile:

```
#Deriving the latest base image
FROM python:alpine

# Any working directory can be chosen as per choice like '/' or '/home' etc
WORKDIR /app

#to COPY the remote file at working directory in container
COPY . .

# has to be after WORKDIR because Python will only have all files within its path
RUN pip3 install python-tado

ENV USERNAME=username
ENV PASSWORD=password

CMD ["python", "-u", "script.py"]
```

Comment: Any idea? I could build another multi-platform image with nodeJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I can answer the question myself. On my main PC with Windows 11 it worked without a problem. So it makes sense that my ARM device can only build an image for arm64 and not also for amd64 as the PC can.

Rookie mistake I guess.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: I restarted my Docker Desktop Host machine and it was fixed (maybe restarting all docker-related services would have fixed it also).

I just now had the exact same problem, i ran a multiplatform build using a custom qemu builder instance on my windows machine. I was building for `linux/arm64,linux/amd64,linux/arm/v6,linux/arm/v7` which my builder was compatible with. At the first Dockerfile instruction (apart from WORKDIR/FROM) the builder failed with the error: `failed to solve: process "..." exit code 135` and that qemu got an unexpected signal 7. Seems like somehow my running instance of builder was corrupted and a restart fixed the issue.